# how to bind IP address to a domain name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

we currently have a completed rails app and are looking to deploy on a local secured network. To have all devices on secured network access the site I bound my IP address with

```
bundle exec rails server --binding= <ip-address>
```

It works perfectly however we don't want to release the IP address of the computer running the app so how can I set an ip dress t o a host name? Thanks

Comment: You don't bind to a name, you bind to an IP. Your domain nameserver settings translate names (www.yoursite.com) into an IP (1.2.3.4). If you need to hide the IP of the computer running the server, you need to run it behind a reverse proxy (which will itself have a publicly visible IP).

Comment: how can I tie then a created domain name to my app? this is for secure network so we aren't using any hosting services

Comment: You would need to set up local DNS server, but then tell every user on this network to use this DNS server (https://likegeeks.com/linux-dns-server/)

Comment: or connect to the platform that offers you domain name purchase and go to the section that allows you to parameter DNS (this is not easy for a beginner as you have to know concepts such as A, CNAME etc .. but you can learn from online resources)

Comment: would there be a way to set localhost so that all on the network can access it? as in I launch it and you type in "localhost:3000" and it pulls it up from any computer? I bound it to 0.0.0.0 but I cannot view from another computer with local host, I'm wondering if it is because of firewall